# How to select last quarter / last 2 months of data in Amazon Redshift query

Tags: date, datetime, amazon-redshift, where-clause, intervals

I know this is a simple question, but I just started to explore Redshift and couldn't google the answer yet.

In MSSQL server I use the following WHERE CLAUSE:

Last quarter:

```
WHERE DateTime>= DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq,0,GETDATE())-1,0) AND DateTime < DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq,0,GETDATE())-0,0)
```

Last 2 months

```
WHERE DateTime>= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-2,0) AND DateTime < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-0,0)
```

In the Redshift for the quarter I came out to:

```
WHERE DateTime>= dateadd(qtr,datediff(qtr,'1970-01-01',current_date)-1,'1970-01-01') AND 
DateTime < dateadd(qtr,datediff(qtr,'1970-01-01',current_date)-0,'1970-01-01')
```

For the last 2 months it looks like:

```
WHERE DateTime>= dateadd(month,datediff(month,'1970-01-01',current_date)-2,'1970-01-01') AND 
DateTime < dateadd(month,datediff(month,'1970-01-01',current_date)-0,'1970-01-01')
```

So, I have to use the unix epoch value instead of 0. Is there any better way to set this up?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Redshift, I would use `date_trunc()` and interval arithmetics.

Last quarter:

```
where datetime >= date_trunc('quarter', current_date) - interval '1 quarter'
  and datetime <  date_trunc('quarter', current_date)
```

Last two months:

```
where datetime >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '2 month'
  and datetime <  date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks much better.